# Get duration of HLS

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to getDuration() of a stream but its always returning -1. I googled many links but none is having the issue solved. I am using videoview for streaming content in my app. However calling `getDuration()` in onPreparedListener is always returning -1.
Here is my code:

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mSeekbar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            Utils.dismissProgressDialog();
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
```

And here is what i am getting upon hitting my m3u8 link:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1900000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
720/720.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=514000,RESOLUTION=854x480
480/480.m3u8
```

I need to have duration because of DVR implementation so need to figure out a way of doing it.

Comment: No expert on M3U, but looking at the [Internet Draft for M3U files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16), I don't think that info is available yet... what do your `720.m3u8` files contain? are there `EXTINF` line(s) giving the duration? I'm guessing the media player can't get the length until these are loaded.

Comment: Live or VOD? There's no duration for live events.

Comment: I ended up using ExoPlayer which is showing duration itself and also allowed me to change skin of player controls.